# Exchange : Minimum permissions to send email through c#

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server

In an web site, i've developed a function to send email (i.e. connect to exchange). I need to use a special user that in Active Directory has the permission to send mass email. On the other hand, this user shouldn't have the ability to logon to a computer.
In Active Directory, what permissions should be changed or revoked?

Comment: I don't see how this is a C# question. Removed tag. Are you sure this is even a programming question? This may be better suited for Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: If you have done it before (i.e. c#) then you know the minimal permissions, because you have asked to be done. You can delete the question if you still think it's not suitable.